# Can't load value since first database call arent finished

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

Im trying to retrieve the sellers name from the books seller uid which is the user id.

Though it seems like when trying to load the user name seller = null since the first call to the database isnt finished..

What to do?

```
state = {
    bookname: '',
    edition: '',
    year: '',
    price: '',
    seller: null,
    sellerName: null,
};
 componentDidMount() {
    const id = this.props.navigation.getParam('id');
    this.loadBook(id);
    this.loadSellerName();
}

loadBook = (id) => {
    firebase
        .database()
        .ref(`/Books/${id}`)
        .once('value', snapshot => {
            const book = snapshot.val();                
            const { bookname, edition, year, price, seller } = book;
            this.setState({ bookname, edition, year, price, seller });
        });
};

loadSellerName = () => {

    const result = firebase
        .database()
        .ref('/users')
        .child(this.state.seller)
        .once('value', snapshot => {
            const name = snapshot.val().name;                
            const sellerName = name;
            this.setState({ sellerName });
        });
    console.log(result);

};
```

Comment: move this.loadSellerName() inside the once of loadBook?

Comment: @Ninja420 ty so much! Works :)

Comment: @Ninja420  may be you can add this as an answer, before somebody post an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the asynchronous API calls. It may be best to do it as below

```
state = {
    bookname: '',
    edition: '',
    year: '',
    price: '',
    seller: null,
    sellerName: null,
};
 componentDidMount() {
    const id = this.props.navigation.getParam('id');
    this.loadBookAndSeller(id); // move this.loadSeller() to after the firebase responds
}

loadBookAndSeller = (id) => {
    firebase
        .database()
        .ref(`/Books/${id}`)
        .once('value', snapshot => {
            const book = snapshot.val();                
            const { bookname, edition, year, price, seller } = book;
            this.setState({ bookname, edition, year, price, seller });
            this.loadSellerName(seller); //pass the argument directly since setState can also be asynchronous
        });
};

loadSellerName = (seller) => {
    const result = firebase
        .database()
        .ref('/users')
        .child(seller)
        .once('value', snapshot => {
            const name = snapshot.val().name;                
            const sellerName = name;
            this.setState({ sellerName });
        });
    console.log(result);
};
```